# Scala recursive function values definition

Tags: function, scala, recursion

This non compiling code on defining a recursive function value,

```
val factorial = (n:Int) => if (n < 1) 1 else n * factorial(n-1)
```

produces an error message such as

```
recursive value factorial needs type
```

How to declare the return type ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this

```
val factorial: Int => Int = (n:Int) => if (n<1) 1 else n*factorial(n-1)
```

In fact, I would write it like so:

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int = if (n < 1) 1 else n * factorial(n-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val factorial: Int => Int = (n) => if (n<1) 1 else n*factorial(n-1)
```